# Unable to print json output

Tags: php, json, web-services

I saved this file on my web server and authentication.php is there, but I was unable to display json output data in the web browser using this file. When I load it in the web browser there was no output or error... please help me.

> authentication.php is a xml webservice to the server and this file
>   gets data from that file, now the problem is, I'm trying to convert
>   the incoming data into json and send them to google sheets using
>   google appscript, the app script should catch the in json format

---

```
<?php 
// Boutique_Hotels_web_srv
require_once('authentication.php');

//print_r($key);
$result = $client->UseService(array('Key' => $key, 'ServiceName' => 'Boutique_Hotels_web_srv'))->UseServiceResult;
//print_r($result);

$data = array();
$data = $result->string;
$wtst_id = 1;

if(count($data) > 0){
$db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "where_to_stay WHERE wtst_id = '" . (int)$wtst_id . "' "); 
}

foreach($data as $data=>$hotel){
$hotel_data = explode('|', $hotel);

$tags = '';
if($hotel_data[18] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Night Life';
}
if($hotel_data[19] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Ballooning';
}
if($hotel_data[20] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Diving, Snorking';
}
if($hotel_data[21] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Golf';
} 
if($hotel_data[22] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Surfing';
}
if($hotel_data[23] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Fishing';
}
if($hotel_data[24] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Caving';
}
if($hotel_data[25] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Water Skiing';
}
if($hotel_data[26] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Rock Climbing';
}
if($hotel_data[27] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', kayaking, canoeing';
}
if($hotel_data[28] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', wildlife safari';
}
if($hotel_data[29] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', agro tourism';
}
if($hotel_data[30] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', whale and dolphin watching';
}
if($hotel_data[31] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', White water rafting';
}
if($hotel_data[32] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Shopping';
}

return $hotel;

$myObj->hotel__data0 =$hotel_data[0];
$myObj->hotel__data10 =$hotel_data[10];
$myObj->hotel__data32 =$hotel_data[32];

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;

}

?>
```

Comment: `print_r($hotel)`

Comment: ok I resolved , with a fb group

Comment: with `return $hotel;` you end the execution right there, so the JSON part is not reached. Also, what exactly does the `authentication.php` do? As @BhargavChudasama suggested, `print_r` the contents of the variables from top to bottom until you see where your script has unexpected behavior. You need to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program.

Comment: @SandunDayananda either remove the question if its not relevant anymore or provide the answer yourself for others to profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I resolved , with a fb group  Vasile Ţucă helped me

```
<?php 
// Boutique_Hotels_web_srv
require_once('authentication.php');

//print_r($key);
$result = $client->UseService(array('Key' => $key, 'ServiceName' => 'Boutique_Hotels_web_srv'))->UseServiceResult;
//print_r($result);

$data = array();
$data = $result->string;
$wtst_id = 1;

if(count($data) > 0){
$db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "where_to_stay WHERE wtst_id = '" . (int)$wtst_id . "' "); 
}

foreach($data as $data=>$hotel){
$hotel_data = explode('|', $hotel);

$tags = '';
if($hotel_data[18] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Night Life';
}
if($hotel_data[19] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Ballooning';
}
if($hotel_data[20] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Diving, Snorking';
}
if($hotel_data[21] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Golf';
} 
if($hotel_data[22] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Surfing';
}
if($hotel_data[23] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Fishing';
}
if($hotel_data[24] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Caving';
}
if($hotel_data[25] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Water Skiing';
}
if($hotel_data[26] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Rock Climbing';
}
if($hotel_data[27] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', kayaking, canoeing';
}
if($hotel_data[28] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', wildlife safari';
}
if($hotel_data[29] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', agro tourism';
}
if($hotel_data[30] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', whale and dolphin watching';
}
if($hotel_data[31] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', White water rafting';
}
if($hotel_data[32] == 'True'){
$tags .= ', Shopping';
}

$myObj["hotel_data0"] = $hotel_data[0];
$myObj["hotel_data10"] = $hotel_data[10];
$myObj["hotel_data32"] = $hotel_data[32];

$myJSON = $myObj;

var_dump($myJSON);


}

?>
```

this is the correct code